# Exception Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteWatchdog while running Headless Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I have been trying to run headless chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, have downloaded the latest Chrome Driver (2.32 for Linux x64) 
here is the code, I have written the following code:

```
package com.test.tests;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ChromeHeadlessTest {

    @Test
    public void testExecution() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources/linux/chromedriver");

        // Add options to Google Chrome. The window-size is important for responsive sites
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://google.co.in");

        // a guarantee that the test was really executed
        assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo")).isDisplayed());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

When I run this test as TestNG Test, I get the following error:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.2
[TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse-1039732738/testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED: testExecution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteWatchdog
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:176)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:158)
    at com.highq.test.tests.ChromeHeadlessTest.testExecution(ChromeHeadlessTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchdog
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 35 more
```

I have searched a lot for the fix but could not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**1st Error**

First of all your heading error is different which is related to Apache poi jar error which can be removed by below solution.

Adding commons-logging.jar should solve this type of issue

```
commons-logging.jar
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

**2nd Error**

As per error you have posted, your path of Chrome binary is not correct or Chrome binary is not placed at the same location.

You need to download the Linux binary from below location :

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/

Note:- download binary as per your OS which seems Linux in your case.

Comment: Shubham - Edited & updated  correct error - Actually I was trying with other executable so while posting the question initially, the error was incorrectly pasted, The actual error is ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteWatchdog, Please check the complete error log again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your driver isn't initialized.
From this line:

```
The driver executable does not exist: /usr/bin/chrominum-browser
```

First of all make sure that chromedriver.exe exists in the above folder.

If that is the case, then you can try a different initialization, like so:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options);
```

Comment: Xwris - Edited & updated  correct error - Actually I was trying with other executable so while posting the question initially, the error was incorrectly pasted, The actual error is ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteWatchdog, Please check the complete error log again

Comment: Hi Ravi, can you also update in your question the xml file you are using to start Testng up? First thing I will check is the build path. From the error it looks that JVM looks for the class in here: org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteWatchdog

Answer (score 0):

Here you have missed the commons-exec-1.3 jar file. Try to add the jar file it will works fine
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/download_exec.cgi